# Vue send base64 with axios, but is null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, post, base64, axios

I have a form with i need to send a couple of images, so i transform every image in a **Base64**, and as you cans see below, the object exist, but when i access *network* from developer tools, the object is empty ! Someone has some idea why this happening ?
[Console.log of object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khTaV.png)

**Post method in vue**

```
this.topografiaItems.forEach(function(topografia) {
                    topografia.anexos.forEach(function(anexo, index) {
                        let reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.readAsDataURL(anexo);
                        reader.onloadend = function () {
                            topografia.anexos[index] = reader.result;
                        };
                        reader.onerror = function () {
                          console.log('Error', error);
                        };
                    });
                });

                console.log(this.topografiaItems);
                axios.post(this.path, this.topografiaItems,{
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                }).then( (response) => {
                   console.log(response);
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reader.readAsDataURL(anexo);` is asynchronous. The `forEach` looping is synchronous. The `axios.post` is happening before data is actually loaded.
One solution is to use a promise wrapper and [for of iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to wait

Something like https://codesandbox.io/embed/cranky-cherry-oxvhg

Comment: Thanks so much! First of all, your answer helped out to the follow items. Like you said, the **Reader** class is asynchronous,  so i had to wrap my function in a promise what solved the top-level problem. The other problem is i am doing that in a loop, and i cannot change the value is a reference, what lead me to a round about solution (https://codepen.io/Spenttie/pen/QWLVwKK), but work perfectly. If anyone has a better implementation please share ! Thanks

Comment: If you used `let` instead of `const` in  the `for of` iterators that you are using, you should be able to change. There is no "best" solution. Some prefer mutation and some dont.  For non mutation, it would be better to get a new array out of this iteration and then use that in your post call

Comment: Again, thanks ! I din't pay attention to const. Changing that everything words perfectly. Pen Updated